# How does an email client receive updates/messages?

Tags: email, ip, nat, ipv4

From my very rudimentary understanding of the IP protocol, most devices (such as my smartphone, my laptop, my desktop, etc) are not directly exposed to the internet as they have to communicate through a router (most of the time anyway).

When a random person in New York or Africa or anywhere sends me an email, I receive a notification on my phone within seconds.  My question is how does the email server track my phone (since my phone does not have any unique IPv4 address), when my phone could be anywhere?

Does my phone have to constantly ask the server for updates once a second?  Or does my phone alert the server of its network location each time its location changes?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could clear this up for me; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You phone may keep established outgoing connection to IMAP server supporting `IDLE` command.  It allows to receive "near real time" notifications about new messages in IMAP INBOX.

[IMAP PUSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_email)
[IMAP IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE)